# Does a generic linear map admit a vector whose iterates span $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, measure-theory

We say a linear map $T$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ admits spanning vectors if there exists some vector $v \in V$ whose iterates $v, Tv, T^2 v, \dots$ under $T$ span $V$.

**Question:** Consider the set of linear maps on $\mathbb R^n$, viewed as $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ under the Lebesgue measure.
Is it true that almost every linear map admits spanning vectors?

Comment: I think the usual term for $v$ is a [cyclic vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_vector).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose that $\dim(V)=n$. I claim that whenever $v$ is a vector, then $(v,Tv,\dots,T^{n-1}v)$ spans $V$ for almost every linear transformation $T\in L(V)$. To see this, observe that $(v,Tv,\dots,T^{n-1}v)$ spans $T$ if and only if $\text{Det}(v,Tv,\dots,T^{n-1}v)\neq 0$. But $\{T:\text{Det}(v,Tv,\dots,T^{n-1}v)=0\}$ is a zero set of a real analytic function, and I have shown that the zero set of any non-zero real analytic function has measure zero [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436208/22277).

Comment: Ah, very nice proof.

Comment: Whenever $v$ is nonzero.

Comment: technically you need to show that this real analytic function is not identically zero.  But that's easy to do by finding a single T for which the determinant is nonzero, which is easy.